# Keyboard input using windows API c++

Tags: c++, windows, api, input

I really need some help here. I am trying to create an input system using the windows api, but I really cannot understand how to use it. I got the code below from

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/keyboard-input

I understand that it returns some kind of result depending on the key pressed, but how do I actually get the result that is returned from this function? How do I use it? Any help would be appreciated.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    wchar_t msg[32];
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
        swprintf_s(msg, L"WM_SYSKEYDOWN: 0x%x\n", wParam);
        OutputDebugString(msg);
        break;

    case WM_SYSCHAR:
        swprintf_s(msg, L"WM_SYSCHAR: %c\n", (wchar_t)wParam);
        OutputDebugString(msg);
        break;

    case WM_SYSKEYUP:
        swprintf_s(msg, L"WM_SYSKEYUP: 0x%x\n", wParam);
        OutputDebugString(msg);
        break;

    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        swprintf_s(msg, L"WM_KEYDOWN: 0x%x\n", wParam);
        OutputDebugString(msg);
        break;

    case WM_KEYUP:
        swprintf_s(msg, L"WM_KEYUP: 0x%x\n", wParam);
        OutputDebugString(msg);
        break;

    case WM_CHAR:
        swprintf_s(msg, L"WM_CHAR: %c\n", (wchar_t)wParam);
        OutputDebugString(msg);
        break;

    /* Handle other messages (not shown) */

    }
    return DefWindowProc(m_hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: This function does not return anything, it's an event processor for a window. To use this function you have to add your code to this function. The Windows API is *event driven*, each key press is a seperate event. This code catches those events. If you want to process key press events you add your code to the above function and set the function as an event processor for your window. You should review this section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/writing-the-window-procedure

Comment: Incidentally, that tutorial seems really sketchy to me. I'd look for something a bit more in depth if you've never done this kind of programming before.

Comment: @john I thought that tutorial was the best place to start. I've been trying to find for a better one since yesterday. Thanks for explaining how it works though. It was really helpful. So I don't have to make any function calls? The event will trigger automatically?

Comment: If a window has the focus, then it will recieve keyboard events automatically..

Comment: If tutorials don't work for you, get Petzold's [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X).

Answer (score 0):

Unlike MS-DOS-based applications, Windows-based applications are event-driven. They do not make explicit function calls (such as C run-time library calls) to obtain input. Instead, they wait for the system to pass input to them. The system passes all input for an application to the various windows in the application.

Each window has a function, called a window procedure, that the system calls whenever it has input for the window. The window procedure processes the input and returns control to the system.

Your code is just implement WindowProc which wait for windows messages and handle theme, the information of received message is available using the parameters of implemented function.

You can find useful information about Windows messaging system [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#system_defined).

And here is a documentation of [WM_SYSKEYDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-syskeydown)  for example.

And here documentation of [WindowProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573(v=vs.85).aspx) .

Read the documentation carefully help you understand the underlying system behind Windows messaging system.

Comment: MS-DOS doesn't exist any more (unless you have a really old computer). 'Console based applications' would be more accurate.

Comment: GUI programs use a system call (e.g. `GetMessage` -> `NtUserGetMessage`) to enter the window manager's kernel routine for pumping messages posted/sent to the thread or windows owned by the thread. Console applications instead block on a File I/O system call such as `NtReadFile` or `NtDeviceIoControlFile`. This call is ultimately serviced by an instance of conhost.exe, the console host process. conhost.exe of course has a thread that handles the console window and transforms GUI window messages into console input records on behalf of its client applications.